# Managing docker image throw systemctl

Tags: nginx, docker, systemd, systemctl

I built a docker image containing Nginx with its configuration lets call it A 
when I build it manually  its building and running with no errors however when I decided to manage the docker image throw systemctl it's giving me no errors either but when type:
sudo systemctl status A.
service it's inactive(dead)

[Here is my nginx.service file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZohOz.png)

[Here is the output given when managed throw systemctl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qzYY.png)

what can I do to make it active on startup? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't kill a non existing container like the one on your ExecStartPre field. You can first : check if the container is running and kill it if needed. I think it's too complicated.

If you have a recent docker version (> 1.10), prefer restart policies : https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/

```
docker run --restart always mynginx
```